# How to convert this kind of Date (don't know which format it is)?

Tags: c#, date

I get this kind of data from XML document :

```
2012-08-29T18:18:00+02:00
```

and I'd like to convert it with the DateTime object. So I can manage it as I want, getting only day and/or month.

But if I do it :

```
DateTime.Parse("2012-08-29T18:18:00+02:00").Date
```

I get somethings like `\/Date(1346191200000)\/` :O

Where am I wrong? I think I need to specify the type of date when I parse it?

---

After the suggestions, I tried with this data :

```
string dataStr = "2012-11-15T13:50:58+01:00";
DateTime data = DateTime.Parse(dataStr).Date;
Response.Write(data.Hour + "<br />");
```

but the output is `0`, so the time is missing. Why?

Comment: `DateTime.Parse` seems to work fine on that format. Might your issue be with actually _displaying_ the resulting `DateTime`?

Comment: It's an RFC3339-date, which makes it also qualify as an ISO8601-date.

Comment: Where did you get this value `\/Date(1346191200000)\/`? And how you are displaying your date?

Comment: I print the object with `jsonSerializer.Serialize`

Comment: Check the updated! The time will vanish?!?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your latest update:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact("2012-11-15T13:50:58+01:00", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK", null);

Response.Write(d.Hour + "<br />");
```

Comment: And I'd like to print directly the date + time? Tried `d.Date` but it is 0 :O

Comment: How you print? With Response.Write. Can you debug your code to check value of d variable?

Comment: I mean : the only way I see to print the Date + Time shortly is `d.ToShortDateString() + " - " + d.TimeOfDay`

Comment: Here is a link how to format datetime output. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It is the standard format used in xmls and all xml parser should handle it correctly. You don't need to parse it. 
Using Linq2Xml, for example, All you have to do is casting it to a DateTime object

```
XElement xElem = new XElement("Time", "2012-08-29T18:18:00+02:00");
var dt = (DateTime)xElem;
```